# Gulp terminates immediately when running gulp watch

Tags: npm, gulp, node-modules, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

When I run 'gulp watch' in my terminal, I get this response:

```
[13:59:40] Using gulpfile ~/path/to/gulpfile.js
[13:59:40] Starting 'watch'...
[13:59:40] Finished 'watch' after 45 ms
```

Here is the relevant code from my gulpfile.js:

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src([baseDir + '/sass/style.scss',baseDir + '/sass/events/events.scss'])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 10 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(baseDir + '/css'))
        .pipe(livereload());
});

// watch
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    livereload.listen();
    gulp.watch(baseDir + '/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

My problem is this: when I make a change in a .scss file, it is not recognised in the terminal.. why is this?

My gulp version is

```
version 3.9.1
Local version 3.9.1
```

Comment: `return gulp.watch(baseDir + '/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);` ?

Comment: baseDir is imported the the top of the file, and refers to the first part of the path. So for example: './project', so that together, this makes: './project/sass/**/*.scss'

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. It doesn't look like you are returning the `gulp.watch`. You need to add `return` into your watch task.

Comment: unfortunately, I get the same response..

Comment: And your gulpfile.js is at the same level as the project folder?  Not within it?

Answer (score 0):

When this happens I assume my directory is off. No errors? No files, lol. Have you tried replacing baseDir with a hard coded call to the directory and see what happens? example

```
gulp.watch('app/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
```

and see what happens?